# <method-wrapper '__call__' of functools.partial object at 0x1356e10> is not a Python function

Tags: python, partial, functools, rx-py

I'm trying to build a function which I can use as a handler for an RxPy stream that I'm mapping over. The function I have needs access to a variable outside the scope where that variable is defined which, to me, means that I need to use a closure of some kind. So I reached for functools.partial to close over the one variable and return a partial function that I can pass to as an observer to my stream.

However, doing so results in the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "retry/example.py", line 46, in <module>
    response_stream = message_stream.flat_map(functools.partial(message_handler, context=context))
  File "/home/justin/virtualenv/retry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rx/linq/observable/selectmany.py", line 67, in select_many
    selector = adapt_call(selector)
  File "/home/justin/virtualenv/retry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rx/internal/utils.py", line 37, in adapt_call_1
    argnames, varargs, kwargs = getargspec(func)[:3]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 816, in getargspec
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func))
TypeError: <method-wrapper '__call__' of functools.partial object at 0x2ce6cb0> is not a Python function
```

Here is some sample code which reproduces the problem:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from rx import Observable, Observer
from pykafka import KafkaClient
from pykafka.common import OffsetType
import logging
import requests
import functools


logger = logging.basicConfig()


def puts(thing):
    print thing


def message_stream(consumer):
    def thing(observer):
        for message in consumer:
            observer.on_next(message)

    return Observable.create(thing)


def message_handler(message, context=None):
    def req():
        return requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get')

    return Observable.start(req)


def handle_response(message, response, context=None):
    consumer = context['consumer']
    producer = context['producer']
    t = 'even' if message % 2 == 0 else 'odd'
    return str(message) + ': ' + str(response) + ' - ' + t + ' | ' + str(consumer) + ' | ' + producer


consumer = ['pretend', 'these', 'are', 'kafka', 'messages']
producer = 'some producer'
context = {
    'consumer': consumer,
    'producer': producer
}
message_stream = message_stream(consumer)
response_stream = message_stream.flat_map(functools.partial(message_handler, context=context))
message_response_stream = message_stream.zip(response_stream, functools.partial(handle_response, context=context))
message_stream.subscribe(puts)
```

The problem seems to be that my partial function returns `False` when calling `inspect.isfunction`.

How can I make my partial function pass this check? Is there a way to easily convert a partial function into a "real" function type?

Comment: Where's your code? It should be here.

Comment: Partial functions should still be function objects. I second Marcin - we can't debug this without seeing the function you're wrapping, the code that does the wrapping, and the call to your partial function would help too.

Comment: Does the factory in the `decorator` module help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're asking if it's actually a function, and it's telling you isn't not a function. It's a method-wrapper.

You want to [duck-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

```
>>> def printargs(*args):
...     print args

>>> import inspect
>>> from functools import partial
>>> inspect.isfunction(printargs)
True
>>> f = partial(printargs, 1)
>>> inspect.isfunction(f)
False
# try duck-typing, see if the variable is callable
# check does it work for a method-wrapper?
>>> callable(f)
True
# check an integer, which should be false
>>> callable(1)
False
# ensure it works on an actual function
>>> callable(printargs)
True
```

This is why you duck-type. You don't care if it's a function. You care if it acts like a function.

EDIT:
You could, if desperate enough, write a class and pass a reference to a function in the class.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, frozen, *args, **kwds):
        self.frozen = frozen
        self.args = args
        self.kwds = kwds

    def call(self):
        self.frozen(*self.args, **self.kwds)
```

Then just use A(f).call as your wrapper.

```
>>> f_ = A(f)
>>> inspect.ismethod(f_.call)
True
>>> f_.call()
(1,)
```

This works as long as ismethod works.

If not, you really need a decorator.

Final EDIT:
If you are truly desperate enough and don't want to write a custom decorator, you could use a lambda function with a tuple to pass to make a partial-like function.

Ex.:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def printargs(*args):
...     print args
>>> a = (1,2,3)
>>> f = lambda x: printargs(*x)
>>> f(a)
(1, 2, 3)
>>> inspect.isfunction(f)
True
```

Comment: The problem is that the `inspect` module is doing this check though.

Comment: If you're desperate enough, you can write a class and give it a function bound to the class. I'll add it in.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is that I don't have control over the code that calls out to `isfunction`. The library I'm using, RxPy, is doing that under the covers.

Comment: @JustinValentini: You should report a bug to RxPy.

Comment: @JustinValentini, I added in a lambda solution if you don't want to write a function decorator. It's simple and works.

I still recommend filing a bug report: forcing something to be a function necessarily stops class methods, method-wrappers, static methods, and many other valid arguments that act like functions.

RxPy should check if the actual variable has a __call__ attribute, not whether it is a function. That's a design flaw.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh, yeah I ended up just wrapping my partial in a lambda to fix it. I also filed a bug report here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY/issues/51. Thanks for confirmation that this is a design flaw.

Comment: I would specifically mention that the issue is one of design, that their library should use duck-typing rather than make rash assumptions solely based on the argument's type.

Anything with a __call__() attribute should in theory be allowed in the library.

Comment: @JustinValentini, after looking at the source, I added in some thoughts on the bug tracker.

It seems to work with methods as well.

Comment: just wanted to note, don't do `hasattr(item,'__call__')`, do `callable(item)` ;)